# Can I receive a package in Zurich airport while on transit?

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, switzerland, mail, zrh

In a few weeks I will have a flight with few hours transfer in Zurich. I will have several hours and I can leave the transfer zone, it won't be enough to leave the airport though.

Let's say I want to order something from an online shop located in Switzerland, is there any way to get it delivered to the airport so I could pick it up during my transfer?

Comment: This seems to be about logistics rather than travel. I assume it's up to the parcel service whether or not billing- and shipping adress have to be the same.

Comment: What are you going to give as a delivery address? Zurich, Airport, and then?

Comment: @Neusser presumably anyone who knows whether there "is any way to get it delivered to the airport" would know how to address the package.

Comment: @Neusser: That seems to be what he's _asking_.

Comment: @Neusser I don't know about Switzerland, but I've received parcels at the post office in a few airports in Asia. One could surmise that in a country as organised as Switzerland it could be possible...

Comment: @dda, that was what came to my mind, send it "Poste restante" to the post office. There needs to be one in the airport, though, not sure it's the case. Let's check...

Comment: Yep, there is one. Just need to send the parcel to Mr or Mrs Firstname Lastname, Poste restante, 8060 Zürich. Note that this probably works only if the parcel is actually sent by Post rather than one of the alternative parcel delivery companies...

Comment: @jcaron:  That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: https://places.post.ch/?topic=2&PreselectText=Post+Branch+8060+Z%C3%BCrich+60+Flughafen&from_directentry=True&lang=en&service=places PickPost service at Zürich Flughafen :-)

Comment: @dda had started mentioning it, but Pickpost is open only to swiss residents.

Comment: @jcaron ah good catch. Poste restante then.

Comment: The train takes about 30 minutes or less between the airport and the Main Station (Hauptbahnhoff). Depending how your time there coincides with departure times of the train and where you'd like to be, I'd say 2 hours or more available might just be sufficient for a quick jaunt into town. (See timetables at www.sbb.ch.) Public transport in Zürich is quite good.

Comment: @fr13d That might be enough time to get out of the airport, on the train, downtown for the pickup and back to the airport, but OP has to plan enough time to make it back through security and to the gate, as well. Also, he specified _it won't be enough to leave the airport though_. And, being somewhat frazzled at security with an explanation of "I was flying through and had to go pick up this package" may cause extra delays at security...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can send it "[Poste restante](https://www.post.ch/en/private/receiving-mail/private-specify-receipt-location/poste-restante-consignments)" to the Post office in the airport. Just address it to:

```
Mr or Mrs Firstname Lastname
Poste restante
8060 Zürich
```

The Post Office is located in arrivals 3, and is open every day with pretty long hours (7h30-21h00 Monday-to-Friday, 8h00-21h00 Saturdays and Sundays).

Note however that this will probably work only if the parcel is actually sent by Post, and not through one of the alternative parcel delivery companies.

Some retailers and/or card issuers may also have a problem sending a parcel to a Poste restante address or an address not matching the card's billing address.

And of course you need to be sure the parcel gets there before you do (they will keep it for a month).

Of course, you need to be able to exit the airside, which means entering the Schengen Area if you're in transit between two non-Schengen flights, with all the consequences in terms of visa requirements.

Comment: Any sane online retailer will allow you to enter separate billing and shipping addresses.

Comment: Though this is probably not very frequent in Switzerland, some retailers will only ship to an address that is registered with the credit card provider for security reasons. There are also many retailers who don't ship to PO Boxes, Poste restante, and the like. YMMV.

Comment: Gosh. That would be a huge pain for me. If a parcel's delivered to me at home in the UK, I'm pretty much guaranteed not to be there when it arrives, which means an early-morning trip to the post office to collect it the next day. Probably 95% of what I order online I have delivered either to work or the Amazon locker that's super-conveniently located within 20 meters of my front door.

Comment: In the UK many courier companies won't deliver to "PO Box" addresses, simply because  there is no guaranteed way for them to find out where the "PO Box" is physically located! For example my employers have a PO Box address  for mail, but how would a courier figure out exactly where to deliver something, since the company site is about two miles long and up to half a mile wide? The PO address just says "<name of company>, PO Box xyz, <name of city>. The Post Office know where it is, but they ain't tellin' anyone else!

Comment: @jcaron - "There are also many retailers who don't ship to PO Boxes" AFAIK, that's usually only because they are using a shipping method that cannot deliver directly to/through a Post Office. Otherwise, it's more likely the CC/Payment service that restricts  the delivery address than the retailer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Agreed; same here. One thing to bear in mind, though, is that some retailers insist on the _first_ purchase having matching billing and delivery addresses. Amazon certainly did when I first signed up all those years ago and a few smaller sites have done the same. If this purchase is a first-time jobbie it's not impossible that there would be problems over the address.

Comment: Especially if you consider the whole picture: billed to a foreign credit card, delivered poste restante... Many retailers would find that very risky.

Comment: thus, as others have said *"some retailers {and for anything at all which is expensive} will only ship to an address that is registered with the credit card provider"* ...  this is a basic of modern life, like knowing that you watch movies using Torrent.  It's remarkable anyone wouldn't be aware of this dude!  :O

Answer (score 11):

[This page](https://places.post.ch/?topic=2&PreselectText=Post%20Branch%208060%20Z%C3%BCrich%2060%20Flughafen&from_directentry=True&lang=en&service=places) from Swiss Post shows that the airport in Zürich has a post office with [PickPost Service](https://www.post.ch/en/private/receiving-mail/private-specify-receipt-location/practical-tips-for-recipients/pickpost). It's open 07:30-21:00 though, so not 24/7.

As @jcaron mentions PickPost is only available for Swiss residents. But among services mentioned in the airport post office page is "Receiving letter and parcels" so I guess Poste Restante could work.

Comment: This answer would appear to be the correct one ("You can not do it.") since it seems PickPost is only for nationals??  But wait, you can use "normal" Poste Restante, but not PickPost?  WTH ?

Comment: @Fattie It seems like PickPost has more flexible options than the regular Poste Restante. Anyway. That's still a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic answer but one other option in these circumstances is to phone one of the hotels nearby (preferably with a shuttle bus to the terminal) and ask them if you can have a package delivered to their front desk. Intimate that you’d leave a tip for this.